# use yq version4 to update yaml file

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml, yq

im having the following code which works on yq 3 and when I try to upgrade to yq4 it fails

this works on yq3
`yq w -i dep.yaml 'spec.spec.image' $(MY_VAL)`

on yq4 I got error that it doenst know `w`how can I make it works
I didn't find any match example which can help to my case

https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the section 'Updating / writing documents' of the [migration guide](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v3).

The following command should work for your task with version 4 of [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/):

`dep.yaml` before execution

```yaml
a:
  b: 1
spec:
  spec:
    image: image_old.jpg
c:
  d: 2
```

`MY_VAL="image_new.jpg" yq -i e '.spec.spec.image = strenv(MY_VAL)' dep.yaml`

`dep.yaml` after execution

```yaml
a:
  b: 1
spec:
  spec:
    image: image_new.jpg
c:
  d: 2
```